# MySql Trigger on update,insert and delete

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

there is a way to intercept a new entry record in a table, and insert some value of this fields in another table ? And, again, how can set the relationship to cascade, so that if I delete a record in master table, those record it's deleted even in triggered  table? May we explain by examples/resorce? Thank's in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ins_sum BEFORE INSERT ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW SET @sum = @sum + NEW.amount;
```

In your case you would want to replace the `SET` with an `insert` statment where `NEW` is the instance of your table row being inserted. So something like this:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON tablename
    -> FOR EACH ROW insert into othertable (colname) Values(NEW.colname);
```

Comment: thank's for the reply, but I forgot to specify that Mysql server it's release 3.23 and I can't update it. I had read that in this version the triggers are not available. There is a way to create a function or something that run as a trigger? Thank's a lot

Comment: @GianniGiordano - sorry not sure if you could or how you would go about doing that

Comment: hello, do you know how can I intercept the table update, and copy the new record in other table on version 3.23?